# get names from different tables only having id in Master table using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I have 4 table used to fill combo boxes having id and name and their id's saved in main table now I have tables like:

```
  product|id|name  |     brand |id|name      color |id|name     size|id|name
         |1 |bottle|           |2 |aqua|           |4 |white|        |1|large
```

having the main table storing only their id's and and its own main_id.

**question:** how to get the names of product, brand, color, size using the id? And also the total count of main_id.

In the query I have to give the id myself to get the names:

```
select m.contr_num , m.contr_date , br.brand_name , bu.buyer_name ,
cl.colour_name , mn.manu_name , s.size_name from Scanning_M m inner join 
Brand br on m.id = br.Brand_id,
```

Comment: only i have to click view report button and it should get names from db i have all id's here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have it, you just need to fix the join.  Instead of joining using the ID from the main table `m.id`, you have to join using the product ID `m.product_id` and brand ID `m.brand_id`, etc.

(I'm guessing that the id columns in the main table have the same names as the other tables.)

```
SELECT m.contr_num , m.contr_date , br.brand_name , bu.buyer_name ,
    cl.colour_name , mn.manu_name , s.size_name
FROM Scanning_M m
    INNER JOIN Brand br ON m.Brand_id = br.Brand_id
    INNER JOIN Buyer bu ON m.Buyer_id = bu.Buyer_id
    INNER JOIN colour cl ON m.colour_id = cl.colour_id
    INNER JOIN manu mn ON m.manu_id = mn.manu_id
    INNER JOIN size s ON m.size_id = s.size_id
```